# How to dynamically DELETE in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to do something like that, I need to dynamically delete rows from a table. I dont know anything about the structure of that table beforehand so I am trying to solve everything dynamically.

The following code snippet shows what I am trying to do but I am aware that the except doesn't work with an asterisk. I dont have any Ids or so to delete the item i just want the item from a deletetable to be deleted in the main table. Is there a way to do that?

Thank you very much

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_myprocedure 
    (@tablename NVARCHAR(256),
     @changeId BIGINT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sqlstatement AS NVARCHAR(1000)

    SELECT @sqlstatement = CONCAT('SELECT * INTO ', @tablename,
                                  '_delete FROM ', @tablename,
                                  ' WHERE changeID = @changeId 
                                    SELECT * INTO ',@tablename,'_result_temp 
                                    FROM
                                        (SELECT * FROM ', @tablename,
                                  '_result 
                                   EXCEPT
                                   SELECT * FROM ', @tablename, '_delete)
                                  DROP TABLE ', @tablename, '_result

EXEC sp_rename ''',@tablename,'_result_temp'', ''',@tablename,'_result''  

     ')

    PRINT @sqlstatement
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstatement
END
GO
```

Comment: You **need** to fix those huge injection issues first: [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: Your code doesn't delete anything. You can't use *any* SQL statement unless you *do* know something about the structure. Even if you want to write `DELETE SomeTable where ID=1` you need to know that `ID` exists and that you want to delete the value `1`. You can easily pass that value as a parameter so there's no reason to use dynamic SQL

Comment: What are you trying to do though? It looks like you're trying to copy some data into a history table before dropping the original. Why not just *rename* the original table instead?

Comment: Your first concern in deleting a row in a relational database is to keep relational integrity. If you delete tries to delete a row and it will let another row orphaned it will fail, for good.

Comment: Another option is to move the data as a single partition from the source to the archive table. If, on the other hand, you want to track deletions, you can use SQL Server's built-in Change Tracking, a lightweight mechanism available in all versions and editions since 2005 (I think). In SQL Server 2016 you can use temporal tables to automagically implement history tables

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Most likely, there's no reason to create temporary tables like this

Comment: I am trying to create a stored procedure that returns a historical status of a table - there is manually coded logging already and I need to delete the newly added rows from the resulttable...

Comment: Basically I am trying to create my own versioning

Comment: Another side note: For names of objects there's a special data type `sysname`. You should use that instead of `nvarchar(265)` for `@tablename`.

Comment: Why would using temporal tables fail to solve your problem?